# How does databinding between ContextMenuItems of a DataGridRow and the DataGridRow itself to properties within encapsulated Viewmodel works?

Tags: c#, mvvm, data-binding, datagrid, contextmenu

I know I really should start reading a book about XAML and WPF because I think all my Problems here belong to a lack of understanding about Data Binding (I used WinForms for years):

My Application consists of a TreeView and a DataGrid.

In the TreeView I have added ViewModels for each ParentNode, ChildNode an GrandChildNode.

I've used the sample from Josh Smith [found here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26288/Simplifying-the-WPF-TreeView-by-Using-the-ViewMode).

To be short, he/I used

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate
                    DataType="{x:Type local:ViewModel.TreeViewChildNodeViewModel}"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Children}"> 
</HierarchicalDataTemplate.Resources>
```

to bind the ChildNode to a ChildNodeViewModel and to the corresponding Model.

I than added - in the TreeViewChildNodeViewModel constructor:

```
ContextMenuItems = new List<MenuItem>();
ContextMenuItems.Add(new MenuItem() {
                           Header = "Click",
                           Command = _cmdDoSmth
                           ToolTip = new ToolTip() { Content = "blabla" }
                                    }
);
```

which is exposed to the View with this property:

```
private readonly List<MenuItem> ContextMenuItems;
public List<MenuItem> ContextMenu {
    get { return ContextMenuItems; }
}
```

Note that, I have multiple constructors. I add different ContextMenuItems to the ContextMenu List depending on what Model i want the ViewModel to work with. The "root" ChildNode consist of a:

```
<TextBlock
    Text="{Binding ChildNodeDisplayItem}">
    <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu
            ItemsSource="{Binding ContextMenu}"></ContextMenu>
    </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
</TextBlock>
```

That works like it should. Now my problems start with trying to do some similar with the datagrid.

What I need to achieve is:

I'd like to show rows in the datagrid. Each Row has its own Viewmodel with an exposed List of ContextMenuItem's (as well as the model of course). I'd like to be able to define the count, header and command of each contextmenuitem in dependence of the viewmodel that is selected.

What I did so far:

In my MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Controls:MetroWindow.Resources>
    <ContextMenu  x:Key="DataRowContextMenu" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ActionReactionDataGridViewModel/ContextMenu, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid, Mode=FindAncestor}}"/>
</Controls:MetroWindow.Resources>

<DataGrid   
    AutoGenerateColumns="True"
    AutoGeneratingColumn="OnAutoGeneratingColumn"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
    BorderThickness="1,1,1,1"
    Margin="0,0,0,0"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ActionReactionDataGridViewModel/DataGridSource}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding Path=ActionReactionDataGridViewModel/SelectedDataGridItem}"
    BorderBrush="#FF020202">
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource RowMenu}" />              </Style>
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

In my MainWindowViewModel:

```
    public MainWindowViewModel() // Constructor
    {
        actionReactionDataGrid = new ObservableCollection<ActionReactionDataGridViewModel>();
        actionReactionDataGrid.Add(new ActionReactionDataGridViewModel());

    }

    private ObservableCollection<ActionReactionDataGridViewModel> actionReactionDataGrid;
    public ObservableCollection<ActionReactionDataGridViewModel> ActionReactionDataGridViewModel 
    {
        get { return actionReactionDataGrid; }
    }
```

My ActionReactionDataGridViewModel is here:

```
    public class ActionReactionDataGridViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly List<MenuItem> ContextMenuItems;

    public ActionReactionDataGridViewModel()
    {

        ContextMenuItems = new List<MenuItem>();

        ContextMenuItems.Add(new MenuItem()
                             {
                                Header = "blubb"
                             });

        dataGridSource = new ObservableCollection<ActionReactionDataGridModel>();
        dataGridSource.Add(new ActionReactionDataGridModel("Status","Eventname","Eventtyp","ReaktionName","ReaktionTyp"));
    }

    public List<MenuItem> ContextMenu {
        get { return ContextMenuItems; }
    }

    private ActionReactionDataGridModel selectedDataGridItem;
    public ActionReactionDataGridModel SelectedDataGridItem {
        get { return selectedDataGridItem; }
        set {selectedDataGridItem = value; RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedDataGridItem"); }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<ActionReactionDataGridModel> dataGridSource;
    public ObservableCollection<ActionReactionDataGridModel> DataGridSource {
        get { return dataGridSource; }
        set { dataGridSource = value; RaisePropertyChanged("DataGridSource"); }
    }


}
```

I think posting the content of the model is not neccessary because it just contains the column headers and some sample strings. I think what iam missing is the knowledge of telling the DataGrid Control in the View in MainWindow.xaml to bind the itemssource to "DataGridSource" instead of "ActionReactionDataGridViewModel".

I found other posts on SO about adding Context Menus to a datagridrow. what i was missing is the ability to bind the count, text and command to each viewmodel.

Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

**// EDIT 1**

Ok. finding out how to pass the property of a viewmodel from inside a collection of viewmodels was easy.

i added

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ActionReactionDataGridViewModel/DataGridSource}
```

explanation is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752300%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Now I "just" need to figure out how to add the contextmenu items to each viewmodel...

Answer (score 0):

```
<DataGrid.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem Header="HeaderName">
                    </MenuItem>
                </ContextMenu>
            </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
```

inside menu item you can write your control.

Comment: doenst this cause the contextmenu to show everywhere in the control? i want it to be bount to "ActionReactionDataGridViewModel.ContextMenu" and to the entire row.